# Should I be concerned if the seat spring is a bit loose?

Tags: saddle, winter, japan

Hard to see or even photograph but as is in common in road bikes in Japan the bicycle seat is supported by one/two springs on a hole.

It is cold now about -5C to 5C and the seat now moves up when pulled a bit more than I used and the seat tends to tilt a little. I just worry that this is a precursor to the spring coming out and the seat toppling. Am I right to be concerned?

The two springs visible under the rear of the saddle.

[image]

From https://store.shopping.yahoo.co.jp/chu-ko-bicycle/cre022109068.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The temperature won't have a lot to do with this, unless you're storing the bike outside in the weather when not being ridden.  The saddle is well sheltered by the rider, and the image shows a rear mudguard/fender keeping it all clean and warm.

I'm suspecting that you lift the bike by the saddle, and the suspension springs underneath are intended for compression not tension - ie the rider's weight keeps them in place.  If so, try to lift the bike by the frame or seatpost or even the carrier rack in the future.

If you're concerned about the saddle failing suddenly, they are easily replaced.  Yours is held on by one bolt horizontally, which tightens some clamps against the saddle's rails.  This is also the bolt to loosen if you want to adjust the saddle's angle or fore/aft position.

Should one or both springs fail suddenly, there will be a perception to the rider that the saddle has tilted upward at the nose.  That could be quite disconcerting but is relatively unlikely to cause a problem.

Personally I'd either ride it till it breaks and then replace the saddle, or I'd replace the saddle if it gets worse.

Comment: It is stored under a cover outside. It is at outside temperature of -5 C to 10 C.

Comment: Actually there was a broken cantilever bar. The seat deflection distracted me from noticing it. I didn't what was normal for those seats, Getting the original bicycle shop to replace the seat was only a little more more expensive than buying the seat alone.

Answer (score 2):

Something else to check, along with Criggie's good words.

Looking at the bottom of the seat pull up on the seat in a way that causes the problem you are concerned about and observe what shifts where and identify why the seat is behaving the way it is.

If you can identify what's going on it may give you peace of mind or it may give you something to repair.

The springs on these seats are usually attached by:

1. Molding the ends of the springs into the plastic of the seat on top and riveting the other end into the steel rail on the bottom.
2. Bolting the ends of the springs to the bottom of the seat and bolted into the steel rail on the bottom.

Or a mixture of the two.

If the spring has popped out of the molded plastic you may be able to re-set it. Some super glue or epoxy (epoxy is better) might be needed.

If there is a nut loose or missing then tighten or replace the nut. It should be a standard nut.

I don't remember ever seeing a broken spring but that is a possibility. These seats almost never have parts you can buy for repairs. It wouldn't hurt to do a little looking for parts but often these seats are disposable.

Comment: I suspect OP is lifting the bike by the saddle becuase its convenient, and this may be the root cause.